# Please Help Me Understand Scheme: No Arguments?

Tags: syntax, scheme, arguments

First time stackoverflow user but occasional lurker, hope you guys can help me out.

So the first part of my assignment is to drop all 'leading zeros' in a list.

ex: (0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1) -> (1 0 1 0 1)

To do this, I thought to use an IF statement to check whether the first element was a 0 or not, and to recursively call the rest of the list until the there were no more leading zeros. As I have basically no idea how to program in Scheme, through searching the internet, I came up with what you see below.  However when I run it, DrRacket tells me there are no arguments- I assume this either a syntactical error.. or more likely, I have no idea what I'm doing. So, if you could help me out, I'd really appreciate it!

```
    >(define zz
    >  (lambda (n)
    >    (if (= (car (n)) 0)
    >        (zz (cdr (n)))
    >        ((n)))))
    >
    >(remove '(0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0))
```

The error I get in DrRacket is:

"procedure application: expected procedure, given: (0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0) (no arguments)"

Again, thanks a lot! (P.S. Sorry if the formatting is a little odd...)

*EDIT*

Okay, changing up some stuff, I now get a "expects type  as 1st argument, given: (0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0); other arguments were: 0" error flagged at my if statement.

```
    >(define zz
    >  (lambda n
    >    (if (= (car n) 0)   <----- here
    >        (zz(cdr n))
    >        (n))))
```

*EDIT 2*

```
    >(define zz
    >  (lambda (n)
    >    (if (= (car n) 0)
    >        (zz (cdr n))
    >        n)))
```

It works, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(num)` is not correct - you're trying to call `42` or whatever as a command. (Also, your `if` syntax is off; you may want to do read more code to get a better feel for the syntax).

This should compile:

```
(define remove
  (lambda (num)
    (if (= (car num) 0)
      (remove (cdr num))
      num)))
```

**Parenthesis in Lisp are for calling functions, unless used in quotes.**

---

Okay, the OP asked about a general rundown of the syntax for Scheme.

- `a` - A symbol, which is looked up by the evaluator and substituted for its value. Some symbols (such as `42`) evaluate to themselves.
- `'a` - This "quotes" the symbol and transforms it into `(quote a)`. `quote` prevents its argument from being evaluated - instead, the value `a` is returned. *Not* the string "a", *not* the result of looking up `a`, `a` itself. This also works for lists (`'(1 2 3)`)
- `(if <expr> <true-value> <false-value>)` - This evaluates `<expr>`, and sees if its value is truthy or not, and executes the corresponding value.
- `(cond (<expr> <true-value>)
         ...
         (else <false-value>))` - This runs though its arguments, and evaluates the `car` of it to see if it is true. If it is, the value of evaluating the `cdr` is returned. Otherwise, it skips to the next value.
- `(define <name> <expr>)` - Sets the value of evaluating the second argument to the name of the first argument.
- `(lambda <arg-list> <body>)` - Creates a procedure which is the result of binding the arguments passed in to the names present in the second argument and evaluating the third argument.
- `(<func> <arg1> <arg2> ... <argn>)` - If the evaluator finds out that none of the above patterns match, then it calls the `car` of the list as a function, with the arguments in the `cdr`.

Comment: @Scheme.Is.Strange Sorry - my call to `=` was off. Check the updated example.

Comment: Yep your code is perfect, do you mind explaining how scheme syntax works? I know my question is vague and asking a lot but just some tips would be nice.

Comment: Okay, I guess I'll get more acquainted with Scheme, thanks a lot!